# installing valgrind on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, valgrind

I'm trying to install valgrind, but the installation failed.

This is what I did:

```
#tar jxvf valgrind−３.7.0.tar.bz2
#cd valgrind−3.7.0
#./configure
#make
#make install
```

Here it says

```
/usr/local/include/valgrind Permission denied.

#sudo apt-get install valgrind-3.7.0
```

Here it says unable to locate package valgrind-3.7.0

Someone please help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically that last part needs to be done as root:

```
sudo make install
```

And to try `apt-get` instead of compiling source, leave off the version:

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

Comment: ok now I deleted the whole folder and run the whole thing again this time:
#./configure
#sudo make
#sudo make install
#sudo apt-get install valgrind
still say unable to locate package
i tried sudo apt-get install v[press tab], it showed me these: vbetool, vim-common, vim-tiny, vinagre, vino

Comment: sorry my comment is all in one line, I dont know how to put new line

Comment: @ubuntuHelp stick to apt-get or compile from source, preferably use apt-get. Please edit the question & add the full error message you're getting

Comment: sorry I am really new to ubuntu and linux, I don't know what compile from source means. Are you referring to make install?

Comment: @ubuntuHelp -- yes, the "configure; make; make install" steps are for compiling from source, which you have downloaded as valgrind−３.7.0.tar.bz2.  The preferable alternative is to install by package using apt-get, when the package is available.  What version of Ubuntu do you have?  Mine (10.04.3 LTS) can run "sudo apt-get install valgrind" just fine.

Comment: oh ok, I think I got it to work now, it works if I compile from source but doesn't work when I install by package. Sorry I had no idea what I was doing. Thanks guys